# How to embed codepen in wordpress (halm and css)

Tags: css, wordpress, embed, codepen

So I discovered a code in codepen that i would like to add to my website. It is of halm and css and i wish to execute the code without embedding codepen entirely. There are no java scripts as far as i know

So far I have tried to copy the css and html code to my wordpress page, am using elementor plugin and oceanwp theme.
here is the link to the pen: https://codepen.io/cells/pen/qzMvjY

```
<iframe height="265" style="width: 100%;" scrolling="no" title="CSS Raindrops (simple version)" src="//codepen.io/cells/embed/qzMvjY/?height=265&theme-id=0&default-tab=css,result" frameborder="no" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true">
```

See the Pen https://codepen.io/cells/pen/qzMvjY/'>CSS Raindrops (simple version) by test
  (https://codepen.io/cells'>@cells) on https://codepen.io'>CodePen.

Just don't know how to go about it.